# Android 10 and 11 CA Cert on Work Profile

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11

Does anyone know how to get a CA cert installed into the System certs or for a particular user?

I have a small application that sets up a work profile and sets itself as the administrator app but I'm unable to locate any work profile specific settings to be able to install certs on that profile.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To install a user or system ca certificate you will need root access either way.

#### To install user certificate into work profile:

1. Install an exported certificate normal way
2. Get a root shell

```
adb root; adb shell
```

3. Verify certificate and hash is installed.

```
# an example would be 1000_CACERT_*
ls /data/misc/keystore/user_0/<CACERT>
```

```
# example: 81c450f1.0
ls /data/misc/user/0/cacerts-added/<xxxxxxxx.0>
```

4. Move them to the work profile

```
cd /data/misc/keystore/
mv user_0/<CACERT> user_10/
```

```
cd /data/misc/user
mkdir 10/cacerts-added
mv 0/cacerts-added/<xxxxxxxx.0> 10/cacerts-added/
```

#### To install system certificate

1. On any rooted device, you can install the certificate into the [system store](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/#3-insert-certificate-into-system-certificate-store), by mounting the system partition as `rw`
2. Or more preferred way, you can install the [MagiskTrustUserCerts](https://github.com/NVISOsecurity/MagiskTrustUserCerts) plugin, which adds the user certs to the system store via a filesystem overlay. This is the suggested solution if you have magisk.